# create a custom extended control ie PasswordField using TextField Class of gluon charm 4.3

Tags: javafx, gluon-mobile

I am creating a appliction using gluon charm 4.3. and i found that there is no password field in that. so i am creating a new component ie PasswordField from the textfield of the gluon charm library

Comment: Please be more precise, have you ever tried something? if so what is the problem encountered?

Comment: actually the library of components i am using does not have any password field so i want to create for my self

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a `PasswordField` why re-invent the wheel:

[PasswordField documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/PasswordField.html)

[Using JavaFX PasswordField](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/password-field.htm#CHDIAAAJ)

Comment: i want to create a password field because there is now passwordfield present in the gluon-mobile library thats why reinventing the wheel